# Custom Object Casting Method

Tags: java, oop, casting

If you have two different classes A and B, and B is a subclass of A, you cannot cast as follows:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
A newA = (A)b;
```

Is there a way to enable the above code to work (no alterations to the above code) without the JVM throwing a ClassCastException?

------------EDIT----------

Sorry, I made a mistake in the code in the above question. The correct version is below:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
B newB = (B)a;
```

Comment: `class B extends A { }`, right? Should work even without the cast.

Comment: In any situation in which an object of type `A` is called for, an object of type `B` is a viable substitute, no casting needed.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It may make sence in the context that dscer is working... this is just a simple example

Comment: Yes, you can "cast" like that.  It's a meaningless cast, because b is already of type A, but it's permitted.

Comment: @AlejoBrz: I misread the question, but apparently the OP also miswrote the question, so we're back where we started!

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It doesn't make any sense (an `A` is not a `B`).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth haha As any good programmer, you red the user's mind.

Answer (score 4):

`B` already has an **is-a** relationship to `A`. You don't need to cast it....You can throw a B at any method or reference that expects/points to an `A`.

Based on your edit -- there is something wrong with your design if you want to do this.  While a `B` **is-a** `A`, the opposite is **NOT** true.  An `A` is not a `B`.  In other words, since `B` extends `A`, it probably has methods/properties on it that are NOT defined on `A`.  If you cast an `A` to a `B`, then methods that accept that reference might try to invoke a method it believes is on the instance, since you told the compiler that it got a `B`, when in reality the underlying `A` does not have the required method.

Casting here will only lead to pain and failure.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simply assign:

```
A newA = b;
```

Answer (score 2):

If `B` is a subclass of `A` the above should work, and the cast would be unnecessary:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
A newA = b; // no need to cast!
```

Answer (score 1):

With new code, no you can't do that. You'd have to create a new object:

```
B newB = new B(a);
```

or

```
B newB = B.of(a);
```

A non-abstract non-leaf class should generally be avoided anyway. Also, since 1.5 (released 2004), there shouldn't be much of the casting syntax about.